# DataReader access data issue

Tags: c#, datareader, hololens

I would like to use DataReader in order read messages sent from a client. Here is my code :

```
private async void Listener_ConnectionReceived(StreamSocketListener sender,
    StreamSocketListenerConnectionReceivedEventArgs args)
    {
        try 
        {
            using (DataReader reader = new DataReader(args.Socket.InputStream)) 
            {
                string receivedData;
                var count = await reader.LoadAsync((uint)reader.ReadInt32());
                receivedData = reader.ReadString(count);
                Debug.Log("Received : " + receivedData);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.Log("Error: " + e.Message);
        }
    }
```

However I receive this error message : **The operation attempted to access data outside the valid range (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000000B)** Any idea ? thanks!

Comment: Can you explain to us what this line is trying to do? `var count = await reader.LoadAsync((uint)reader.ReadInt32());`

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. I tried to follow this example : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/Sharepoint/en-US/7608ce51-55a9-4c2f-bec0-17492ee7a490/read-method-crashes-after-receiving-a-few-packets?forum=wpdevelop

Comment: Yes I saw this page, but I don't see what is stream, where is declared ?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Silvering/120e47453cecfe05ef95dc27355e9554 returns "The name 'stream' does not exist in the current context"

Answer (score 0):

```
(uint)reader.ReadInt32()
```

This code is trying to read an integer at the start of the stream indicating the length of the rest of the data that is being sent through. In all likelihood, the sender is not populating that integer correctly. Ask them to set it.